# Filling in dates

Tags: r

I have a time series of daily rainfall data from 1843-2016 but some of the days in the record are missing completely. I wish to infill dates for the days with missing data and give this a missing N/A code in the rainfall column. Is this possible?

My data takes the form:

```
Year Month Day Rainfall (mm)
1843   1    1     4.3
1843   1    2     0.0
1843   1    3     1.1
1843   1    5     0.0
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can try with `dplyr/tidyr`.  Create a sequence of 'Dates' from the first day of '1843' to last day of '2016', convert it to `data.frame`, `separate` it to 'Year', 'Month', and 'Day', then `left_join` with the original dataset ('df1') so that the missing combinations will have NA in the "Rainfall" column.

```
Dates <- seq(as.Date("1843-01-01"), as.Date("2016-12-31"), by = "1 day")
library(tidyr)
library(dplyr)
data_frame(Dates) %>%
     separate(., Dates, into = c("Year", "Month", "Day"), convert=TRUE) %>%  
     left_join(., df1, by = c("Year", "Month", "Day"))
```

---

Using a reproducible small example

```
df1 <- data.frame(Year = 1843, Month = 1, Day = c(1, 5, 7, 10), Rainfall= c(4.3, 0, 1.1, 0))
Dates <- seq(as.Date("1843-01-01"), as.Date("1843-01-10"), by = "1 day")
data_frame(Dates) %>%
   separate(., Dates, into = c("Year", "Month", "Day"), convert=TRUE) %>%
   left_join(., df1, by = c("Year", "Month", "Day"))
#   Year Month   Day Rainfall
#   <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>    <dbl>
#1   1843     1     1      4.3
#2   1843     1     2       NA
#3   1843     1     3       NA
#4   1843     1     4       NA
#5   1843     1     5      0.0
#6   1843     1     6       NA
#7   1843     1     7      1.1
#8   1843     1     8       NA
#9   1843     1     9       NA
#10  1843     1    10      0.0
```

Comment: This returns: "Error: cannot join on columns 'Year' x 'Year': index out of bounds"

Comment: @DJ-AFC If the column names are the same and have the same class, it should work

Comment: I had to rename the column headers in the original data frame, but when I did that it worked perfectly. Many thanks @akrun